# align 'radio' and 'comment' inside DIV

Tags: css, html

When radio button is selected and successfully updated in the post, 'Success' appears below the radio button, I would like it to appear directly to the right of the radio.

I've tried creating a DIV with 100% and then 2 divs inside that 10% & 90%

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div style="width:10%">  <input type='radio' name="_chkBox" checked="checked" onclick='$("#clientId").val("@client.Id");'/>  </div>
<div style="width:90%">  <p style="color:Green;">Success</p>  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your mark-up as follows:

```
<div>
    <input type='radio' name="_chkBox" />
    <span style="color:green;">Success</span>
</div>
```

If you replace the `p` tag with a `span`, you don't need to worry about the default margins on the `p` tag.

You can apply `display: inline-block` to the `span` if you need to add vertical padding and margins for styling purposes.

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ywXK6/

Comment: i would prefer to do it through the style attribute on the div if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block;`

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div style="width:10%;display:inline-block;">  <input type='radio' name="_chkBox" checked="checked" onclick='$("#clientId").val("@client.Id");'/>  </div>
<div style="width:90%;display:inline-block;">  <p style="color:Green;">Success</p>  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply im afraid this is still not working with inline

Comment: ah yes...thank you kindly sir....on a separate note, 'Success' on the first line appears in bold when selected while on the second line appears as normal...any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Float:left` to first div

`<div>` div is a block element. if you want to make `<div>` same line, make block element to inline element by `display:inline-block` or give `float:left` to the element

http://jsfiddle.net/Lubuu/8/ demo here